# Twitter oAuth 1.1 vb.net (401) unauthorized when posting tweet

Tags: twitter-oauth

I have spent some time on this and cannot figure out why I cannot post to twitter from my web site. I keep getting 401 unauthorized. I think that I was successfully posting to the 1.1 auth at one point but something changed in the last 6 weeks or so (not in my code, did oauth get stricter?).

Does anyone see anything that could be potentially causing the problem? Is there anything I can add to the code to get more info on why it's failing?

```
Private Function NewTweet(status As String) As WebResponse

    Try

        Dim oauth_token = "token"              'access token
        Dim oauth_token_secret = "secret"                'acces token secret
        Dim oauth_consumer_key = "key"                                   'consumer key
        Dim oauth_consumer_secret = "secret"            'consumer secret

        Dim oauth_version As String = "1.0"
        Dim oauth_signature_method As String = "HMAC-SHA1"
        Dim oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))

        Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        Dim oauth_timestamp As String = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        Dim resource_url As String = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

        Dim baseFormat As String = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}"

        Dim baseString As String = String.Format(baseFormat, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token, oauth_version, Uri.EscapeDataString(status))

        baseString = String.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString))

        Dim compositeKey As String = String.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret))

        Dim oauth_signature As String
        Using hasher As New HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey))
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)))
        End Using

        '-------------------------------------------------------
        Dim headerFormat = "OAuth " & _
                            "oauth_consumer_key=""{0}"", " & _
                            "oauth_nonce=""{1}"", " & _
                            "oauth_signature=""{2}"", " & _
                            "oauth_signature_method=""{3}"", " & _
                            "oauth_timestamp=""{4}"", " & _
                            "oauth_token=""{5}"", " & _
                            "oauth_version=""{6}"""

        Dim authHeader = String.Format(headerFormat, _
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), _
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), _
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), _
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), _
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), _
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token), _
                                       Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version))

        '-------------------------------------------------------

        Dim postBody As String = "status=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(status)

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(resource_url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

        Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            Dim content As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody)
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length)
        End Using

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        Return response

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return Nothing

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: It has to do with the way I am url encoding the string that I pass in as status. If I pass in something very simple like "posting a tweet" it works fine. When I use characters like '+' or '-' it 403 unauthorizes me. Apparently *Uri.EscapeDataString(status)* is not correct in all cases?

Comment: More specifically, when I try to post this: "(-129)" the encoding comes out as "(-129)". There is a limitation here and I dont know what it is. vb.net cannot encode a minus sign following a parenthesis?